# Ansible - Vmware guest - No module named requests

Tags: python, ansible

I'm playing around with ansible, I came over the vmware guest module which allows snapshot operation. However, I'm facing some issues. My default python interpreter is Python 3.6.9 i.e if I enter python in my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, Python 3.6.9 is started. Now to the problem I'm currently facing. My playbook is:

```
- name: Snapshot creation on esx-1.damn.li
  hosts: host

  tasks:
  - name: Create snapshot on fw-pfsense-1
    vmware_guest_snapshot:
      hostname: "host"
      datacenter: "esx01.home"
      username: "root"
      validate_certs: no
      password: "dontguess"
      name: "fw-pfsense-1"
      state: "present"
      snapshot_name: "ansible_test"
      folder: "/vmfs/volumes/59714072-384cd3f4-9503-001fc69c0e8f/fw-pfsense-1-2"
      description: "Created by ansible"
```

I execute the playbook with:

```
ansible-playbook esx-1-create-snapshots.yaml -i ../inventory/hosts.yaml --ask-vault-pass
```

And ansible throws:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_vmware_guest_snapshot_payload_gipss3wl/ansible_vmware_guest_snapshot_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/vmware.py", line 24, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

However, if I start python manually and import requests or the necessary module pyVmomi, I can import it.

Comment: Whats in your inventory file? are running this from remote host?

Comment: Inventory is: all:
  hosts:
    host:
      ansible_connection: "ssh"
      ansible_user: "root"
      ansible_ssh_pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          32313630653532653762633530656130393131643464623731376430356563396264333536663737
          3466666334353035313862386331623337336632623338350a643531306137666434663761386235
          66316638306139326433366464383561306237393735383039336239313464613336383765383866
          6631643461353634310a396563396262333236393464343835646439393366656561643238366366
          6464 and yes

Comment: This is your vars file, I'm trying to understand if you are running this module from local connection or the remote host. If you are running this from remote host did you test the import of requests there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the default Ansible will execute the task on the **remote** host, when you need to execute on the manager host locally you should add **`delegate_to: localhost`**

Since **`pyVmomi`** use API to control the vSphere cluster, you should run the task **locally** on the Ansible manager. So your task should be:

```
- name: Snapshot creation on esx-1.damn.li
  hosts: host

  tasks:
  - name: Create snapshot on fw-pfsense-1
    vmware_guest_snapshot:
      hostname: "host"
      datacenter: "esx01.home"
      username: "root"
      validate_certs: no
      password: "dontguess"
      name: "fw-pfsense-1"
      state: "present"
      snapshot_name: "ansible_test"
      folder: "/vmfs/volumes/59714072-384cd3f4-9503-001fc69c0e8f/fw-pfsense-1-2"
      description: "Created by ansible"
    delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [`vmware_guest_snapshot` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vmware_guest_snapshot_module.html)

> **Requirements**
>
> The below requirements are needed **on the host that executes this module**.
>
> - python >= 2.6
> - PyVmomi

PyVmomi currently has as a dependency `requests>=2.3.0`

All the **info you have given** about python in your question is related to what you are using **on the controller** (i.e. the machine running the playbook). You need to **make sure that `pyVmomi` is installed on the target** in the [version of python discovered by ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html) when connecting from the controller.

The easiest way to make sure the requirements are met before you try to use the module is to add the following task in your playbook:

```yaml
- name: Make sure requirements are met to run vmware_guest_snapshot module
  become: true
  pip:
    name: PyVmomi
    state: present
```

Comment: I think this is not true, because operation on esxi hosts is mostly done from remote. Ansible even throws a error, that pip is not installed on esxi. Pip can not even be installed on esxi.

Comment: Operations on esxi host are done by `hosts: host` in you current playbook setting. `host` which is running the `vmware_guest_snapshot` module should not be the esxi host itself but a machine having network access to it, either localhost or an other machine in your inventory. This machine must have `PyVmomi` installed in the used python version.